# how to build mathematic formulation for time violation?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, machine-learning, optimal-transport

I build a mathematical model to find a multi-objective model for the vehicle platooning problem.
I am using the Gurobi optimization tool to build a mathematical model.

The problem I am facing:
Create an objective function for a time violation.
When trucks travel on their shortest path that means there is no time violation.
If the truck travels the longest path that means there will be a time violation.
**The formula is: time violation = latest arrival time – shortest path arrival time**
**If time violation = 0 that means, there is no time violation for all trucks travelling the shortest path.**

The first part of objective function is :

```
objective_function_second_Ipart = gp.LinExpr()
    for h,_ in group.items():
         for e in road_network.edges():
            objective_function_second_Ipart+=x[e][h]*(road_network.get_edge_data(*e)["weight"]/speed)
```

h = trucks, e=edges, x= decision variable truck travels on edges

this 1st part of the objective function for truck time takes on each edge.

```
earliest_arrival_time_each_truck={}
for h, locations in group.items():
   earliest_arrival_time_each_truck[h] = nx.dijkstra_path_length(road_network, source=locations[0], target=locations[1])/speed
```

**next part objective function compares our first part truck time to shortest path time(earliest_arrival_time_each_truck). If the result is 0 that means time violation = 0**

**if time violation>0 = I need to add waiting time to the latest arrival time.**

waiting time means one truck wait for another truck at a merging point.
in the example, truck 0 travel from 1 to 3 time take 1 min
truck 1 travel from 2 to 3  take 2 min that means the truck 0 will wait for truck 1 for
platoon at node 3  so waiting time {0:1,1:0}

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P83PS.png)

$min z = \sum x_e^h (d_e^h / s)$ what is next part?

**the problem I have now is building the next part of the objective function. or make a mathematic formula for time violation based on my model
first part objective function(latest arrival time)
the second part will be something like:  `result = objective_function_second_Ipart - earliest_arrival_time_each_truck`
The next part will be :if result>0 = I need to add waiting time to the latest arrival time
last part will be calculated time violation :** `time_violation[i] = max(latest arrival time[i] / earliest_arrival_time_each_truck[i] - 1 , 0)`

please someone is helping me complete this objective function for minimizing time violation

[mathematical model gurobi code](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4411094107793-How-to-minimize-time-time-violation-in-vehicle-platooning-problem-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A particular step you can take to improve your question is to explain what the "vehicle platooning problem" is.

Comment: Vehicle platooning problem is a transportation problem like vehicle routing problem. In vehicle platooning problem vehicle try to make the drive in a straight line to reduce air drag and reduce fuel consumption.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282162936_The_vehicle_platooning_problem_Computational_complexity_and_heuristics